# Windows 10 uses a different DNS

Tags: windows, dns, dhcp

I configured my routers DHCP to use Level 3 DNS which is 209.244.0.3 and 209.244.0.4 and it is also correctly shown when I check via `ipconfig /all`:

ipconfig dns output:

[image]

But when I check via DNSLeakTest (or any other leak tests) it always shows OpenDNS.

dnsleaktest result:

[image]

I made sure network adapter settings are set to automatic, I tried ipconfig /flushdns and more but still no luck. Also other computers and devices (android, ios) correctly show Level3 on DNSLeakTest. So what might be the cause and how to fix it?

Comment: That is not consistent with your pictures. If your PC used DHCP there should only be the (forwarding) router as DNS server with his internal IPv4/IPv6 addresses.

Comment: @LotPings It is perfectly consistent. DHCP is just used to push DNS configuration to clients, and it can push whatever DNS server addresses you give it. You don't even need to have any DNS forwarder in your LAN at all.

Answer (score 2):

Your ipconfig output shows that your machine is currently configured to use three DNS servers: `fe80::1` and the two you have mentioned. The preferred (primary) one is `fe80::1`, because IPv6 services in general take precedence over IPv4 services. Most of your DNS queries will thus be serviced by this cache.

An address in the `fe80::/16` segment denotes a link-local address, so it most likely belongs to your home router, which is in turn configured to forward all DNS queries to the OpenDNS caches.

If you're wondering how the `fe80::1` got there, it was probably configured automatically using DHCPv6.

Answer (score 1):

I can't repeat your test : If I set my DNS to `209.244.0.3`, then DNS Leak Test
reports it as "Level 3 Communications" in the United Kingdom.

Evidently, you are not using the DNS server you think you are.
I can see these possibilities:

- You made some mistake in entering the DNS server
- Your ISP is hijacking your DNS queries
- Your computer or browser are infected with a DNS hijacker.